# ROS2 on two WLS2 machines

Tags: ros-humble

New to this forum and ROS.

I have two machines running Ubuntu on WSL2. I have installed ROS2 humble on both ubuntuWSL machines. The two machines are connected via local network so pinging them is not a problem.
However, the WSL instances sit behind a virtual ethernet with IP address on different subnets.
Here is the configuration of IPs on both machines:

Machine-1:
Windows IP: 192.168.43.10
WSL IP: 172.26.177.47

Machine-2:
Windows IP:  192.168.43.23
WSL IP: 172.26.1.66

So the ubuntu WSL on machine-1 cannot discover the ubuntu WLS on machine-2. I have tried port forwarding but still same issue.
My understanding is that the ROS node on machine-1 inside the WSL cannot discover the other node on machine-2 (inside the WSL) because they are not different nets.